# Restricting the number of users in wifiDirect

Tags: android, wifi, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p

I have used the basic wifi demo code provide in android sample for developing a app which can connect multiple devices using wifi direct.
I am able to connect multiple devices and perform a Bidirectional communication from server to all the clients and from client to server.

The WIFI direct uses below code to disconnect. But This finction disconnects all the devices (Basiclly disconnects the entire group).

```
manager.removeGroup(channel, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reasonCode) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Disconnect failed. Reason :" + reasonCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {

        }

    });
```

I want to restrict the number of users to 4.Not more than 4 users connects at once.
If the 5th user tries to connect ,Is there any way to disconnect the only 5th user( no other user gets disconected )?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to restrict the fifth user , first create a list of connected devices as they join in . As soon as 4 devices get connected , try     **stopPeerDiscovery(WifiP2pManager.Channel c, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener listener)**. This will prevent other devices discover your device . Also you can **try out cancelConnect(WifiP2pManager.Channel c, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener listener)**  after 4 devices get connected.

Comment: Bahi  Ok let me try this and get back to you.. One more doubt cancelConnect(WifiP2pManager.Channel c, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener listener) is used to cancel on going connection i guess.

Comment: i was trying stopPeerDiscovery(WifiP2pManager.Channel c, WifiP2pManager.ActionListener listener). Inspite of onSuccess call peer Discovery is not stoping. other devices can still see the device.. Do i need to anything else?????

Comment: Is the other device able to connect after u call stop discovery ?

Comment: So you are saying that the other device  is able to still see  the device on which you stopped discovery  and is able to send a connect request because of which you  might be getting a pop up on your other device .??

Comment: yes that is exactly what is happening.I want thet as soon as peer discovery is stopped it must not get discovered by other devices